# Pivot style calculation on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, excel, pivot

I have a MySQL table with a team for a user and for each user there is a player1, player2 & player3 field.

I am trying to calculate a total of a chosen player from all users across as 3 player columns..

I.e.

user1 can pick playerA, playerC & playerG.

user2 can pick playerE, playerF & playerH.

user3 can pick playerB, playerA & playerF.

user4 can pick playerC, playerE & playerA.

I can run a statement against each player column i.e.

```
SELECT player1, count(*) as total from users;
SELECT player2, count(*) as total from users;
SELECT player3, count(*) as total from users;
```

The problem is I need an all encompassing result-set that will show me the total of all the players selected so I would have something like below

```
player        total
playerA       3
playerB       1
playerC       2
playerE       2
playerF       2
playerG       1
playerH       1
```

My table structure is below

```
CREATE TABLE `leaderboard_api` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `competition_id` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player1_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player1_score` tinyint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player2_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player2_score` tinyint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player3_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player3_score` tinyint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_score` tinyint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `missed_cut` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `withdrawn` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

When I run the following

```
select player1_name, count(player1_name) as total from leaderboard_api where year = '2015' and competition_id = '014' group by player1_name order by total desc;
```

I get a list of players and their respective count.  I can then run this for player2_name and player3_name respectively and get their totals too.

The problem I am having is added each players total from each query to another to get a grand total.  I have run each separately and getting the values as expected.

I tried the solution below from @sagi but it's not counting the sum of all 3 queries and just giving me 1 as a total.

```
SELECT t.player,count(*) FROM (
   SELECT player1 as player FROM `users` UNION ALL
   SELECT player2 FROM `users` UNION ALL
   SELECT player3 FROM `users` UNION ALL
   ....) t
GROUP BY t.player
```

This is the top 100 using query

```
select id, player1_name, player2_name, player3_name from leaderboard_api limit 100;
```

Output:

```
1   Donald, Luke    Toms, David Bradley, Keegan
2   Stricker, Steve Bradley, Keegan Watson, Bubba
3   Choi, KJ    Westwood, Lee   Bradley, Keegan
4   Scott, Adam Stricker, Steve Immelman, Trevor
5   Stricker, Steve Garcia, Sergio  Haas, Bill
6   Fowler, Rickie  Schwartzel, Charl   Bradley, Keegan
7   Watney, Nick    Stricker, Steve Levin, Spencer
8   Stricker, Steve Johnson, Zach   Bradley, Keegan
9   Donald, Luke    Points, DA  Fowler, Rickie
10  Westwood, Lee   Donald, Luke    Barnes, Ricky
11  Schwartzel, Charl   Choi, KJ    Haas, Bill
12  Woodland, Gary  Choi, KJ    Garcia, Sergio
13  Donald, Luke    Stricker, Steve Molder, Bryce
14  Garcia, Sergio  Kuchar, Matt    Furyk, Jim
15  Noh, Seung-Yul  Kuchar, Matt    Watney, Nick
16  Donald, Luke    Mickelson, Phil Barnes, Ricky
17  Scott, Adam Fowler, Rickie  Noren, Alexander
18  Johnson, Zach   Molinari, Francesco Toms, David
19  Choi, KJ    Westwood, Lee   Poulter, Ian
20  Mcilroy, Rory   Points, DA  Westwood, Lee
21  McIlroy, Rory   Donald, Luke    Na, Kevin
22  Choi, KJ    Scott, Adam Dyson, Simon
23  Fowler, Rickie  Johnson, Zach   Bradley, Keegan
24  Mcilroy, Rory   Scott, Adam Senden, John
25  Mickelson, Phil Kuchar, Matt    Barnes, Ricky
26  Jimenez, Miguel Angel   Mickelson, Phil Westwood, Lee
27  Donald, Luke    Mcilroy, Rory   Palmer, Ryan
28  Mickelson, Phil Choi, KJ    Poulter, Ian
29  Mcilroy, Rory   Mickelson, Phil Points, DA
30  Johnson, Zach   Stricker, Steve Molinari, Francesco
31  Toms, David Love, Davis Mickelson, Phil
32  McIlroy, Rory   Westwood, Lee   Wilson, Mark
33  Mcilroy, Rory   Garcia, Sergio  Immelman, Trevor
34  Garcia, Sergio  Love, Davis Westwood, Lee
35  Donald, Luke    Stricker, Steve Sabbatini, Rory
36  Mcilroy, Rory   Karlsson, Robert    Romero, Andres
37  Choi, KJ    Yang, Y.E   Toms, David
38  Mcilroy, Rory   Watney, Nick    Kirk, Chris
39  Mcilroy, Rory   Kuchar, Matt    Noren, Alexander
40  Scott, Adam Yang, Y.E   Romero, Andres
41  Donald, Luke    Fowler, Rickie  Jimenez, Miguel Angel
42  Donald, Luke    Jimenez, Miguel Angel   Fowler, Rickie
43  Donald, Luke    Love, Davis Choi, KJ
44  Mcilroy, Rory   Westwood, Lee   Barnes, Ricky
45  Donald, Luke    Fowler, Rickie  Molinari, Edoardo
46  Garcia, Sergio  Choi, KJ    Yang, Y.E
47  Choi, KJ    Fowler, Rickie  Dyson, Simon
48  Fowler, Rickie  Molinari, Francesco Johnson, Zach
49  Stricker, Steve Choi, KJ    Casey, Paul
50  McIlroy, Rory   Choi, KJ    Molinari, Francesco
51  Fowler, Rickie  Jimenez, Miguel Angel   Mickelson, Phil
52  Mcilroy, Rory   Garcia, Sergio  Kim, Kyung-Tae
53  Mcilroy, Rory   Garcia, Sergio  Kim, Kyung-Tae
54  Mcilroy, Rory   Mickelson, Phil Barnes, Ricky
55  Mcilroy, Rory   Mickelson, Phil Barnes, Ricky
56  Fowler, Rickie  Mcilroy, Rory   Wilson, Mark
57  Fowler, Rickie  Love, Davis Watson, Bubba
58  Fowler, Rickie  Harrington, Padraig Poulter, Ian
59  McIlroy, Rory   Mickelson, Phil Jimenez, Miguel Angel
60  Mcilroy, Rory   Fowler, Rickie  Jimenez, Miguel Angel
61  Day, Jason  Johnson, Zach   Bradley, Keegan
62  Stricker, Steve Overton, Jeff   Mickelson, Phil
63  Day, Jason  Furyk, Jim  Toms, David
64  Donald, Luke    Westwood, Lee   Gay, Brian
65  Stricker, Steve Day, Jason  Kim, Kyung-Tae
66  Mahan, Hunter   Stricker, Steve Van Pelt, Bo
67  Day, Jason  Scott, Adam Barnes, Ricky
68  Day, Jason  Johnson, Zach   Love, Davis
69  Fowler, Rickie  Jacobson, Fredrik   Bradley, Keegan
70  Karlsson, Robert    Watney, Nick    Quiros, Alvaro
71  Schwartzel, Charl   Johnson, Dustin Love, Davis
72  Mcilroy, Rory   Scott, Adam Slocum, Heath
73  Day, Jason  Johnson, Zach   Dyson, Simon
74  Day, Jason  Johnson, Zach   Dyson, Simon
75  Day, Jason  Mcilroy, Rory   Garrigus, Robert
76  Donald, Luke    Mcilroy, Rory   Byrd, Jonathan
77  Baddeley, Aaron Garcia, Sergio  Toms, David
78  Day, Jason  Kuchar, Matt    Sabbatini, Rory
79  Johnson, Dustin Choi, KJ    Fisher, Ross
80  Simpson, Webb   Stricker, Steve Yang, Y.E
81  Day, Jason  Mickelson, Phil Barnes, Ricky
82  Johnson, Zach   Howell, Charles Snedeker, Brandt
83  Donald, Luke    Mcilroy, Rory   Stallings, Scott
84  Kim, Anthony    Mickelson, Phil Rose, Justin
85  Kaymer, Martin  Marino, Steve   Westwood, Lee
86  Mahan, Hunter   Kaymer, Martin  Poulter, Ian
87  Mcilroy, Rory   Johnson, Dustin Jimenez, Miguel Angel
88  Mcilroy, Rory   Johnson, Dustin Jimenez, Miguel Angel
89  Laird, Martin   Scott, Adam Snedeker, Brandt
90  Johnson, Dustin Johnson, Zach   Manassero, Matteo
91  Day, Jason  Watney, Nick    Tringale, Cameron
92  Garcia, Sergio  Day, Jason  Quiros, Alvaro
93  Day, Jason  Moore, Ryan Toms, David
94  Day, Jason  Mcilroy, Rory   Barnes, Ricky
95  Baddeley, Aaron Mcilroy, Rory   Yang, Y.E
96  Westwood, Lee   Jacobson, Fredrik   Kim, Kyung-Tae
97  Day, Jason  Mcilroy, Rory   Molinari, Edoardo
98  Day, Jason  Garcia, Sergio  Cink, Stewart
99  Bjorn, Thomas   Scott, Adam Woods, Tiger
100 Day, Jason  Johnson, Dustin Levin, Spencer
```

Comment: Can you show us your original table, or at least a sample from it?

Comment: You should have a junction table with one row per use and per player . . . possibly called `UserPlayers`.

Comment: Added the create table code above if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting started on a solution from @sagi above I eventually worked it out, the counts were missing from the sub table if that's the correct language.

Here's my solution for those that might need it...

```
select t.player, sum(count) as total from (
select player1_name as player, count(player1_name) as count from leaderboard_api where year = '2015' and competition_id = '033' group by player1_name
UNION
select player2_name, count(player2_name) as count from leaderboard_api where year = '2015' and competition_id = '033' group by player2_name
UNION
select player3_name, count(player3_name) as count from leaderboard_api where year = '2015' and competition_id = '033' group by player3_name)
t group by t.player order by total desc
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT t.player,count(*) FROM (
   SELECT player1 as player FROM `users` UNION ALL
   SELECT player2 FROM `users` UNION ALL
   SELECT player3 FROM `users` UNION ALL
   ....) t
GROUP BY t.player
```

Edit: I think you have spaces in your names so they are not grouping as one group , try this:

```
SELECT replace(t.player,' ',''),count(*) FROM (
   SELECT player1 as player FROM `users` UNION ALL
   SELECT player2 FROM `users` UNION ALL
   SELECT player3 FROM `users` UNION ALL
   ....) t
GROUP BY replace(t.player,' ','')
```

You can also try to replace this row:

```
replace(t.player,' ','')
```

With this row:

```
trim(t.player)
```

Depends on how exactly you data looks like.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for but the problem is count is all 1, I'm looking for a total of each occurrence of t.player across all 3 columns.  so the if "player A" appears in player1 3 times and player2 5 times and player3 4 times then the result-set above would should the count for "player A" as 12 if that makes sense?

Comment: And what's wrong with the query I gave you? Thats just what it does. @alan

Comment: It just totals all rows to 1 using the count(*), I'm looking for the actual count of each occurence of t.player so if a playerA appear 3 times in player1 and 4 times in player2 and 5 times in player3 then I should get t.player = playerA and total = 12.  Does that make it any clear?

Comment: Again, I understand what you want and this is what its aupposed to do. I suspect something is not correct with your data or the way its presented. Please update your question and add examples of your data and then what you expect to get from it @alan

Comment: I have updated my question with expected results and the actual query that is giving me the results I expect from the database.  I'm just not sure why it's only counting to 1 but it's giving me the correct list of names returned.

Comment: I need to see the data inside your table, when you run `select id,player1,player2,player3 from users` what results do you get? Paste them here so I'll know whats the issue because my query should work fine. @alan

Comment: Ok I've limited it to the top 100, I over 4k in the table. I wouldn't let me put all the data in a comment so I put it in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108114/discussion-between-alan-and-sagi).

Comment: No it's still just showing the count for each record as 1 with both trim and replace functions but I am getting still the correct number of records expected returned.

Comment: My hosting provider has moved by MySQL over to MariaDB and now my query doesn't allow me to sort properly. @Sagi Is there something I can do to get it working again?